# In Unity Hub, where do I find the Installs tab?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've installed Unity3D, and am trying to get it set up.  I'm using what I think is the official documentation, which refers to the Installs tab (I'm reading this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GettingStartedInstallingHub.html).

My Hub doesn't have an Installs tab - I have "Projects" and "Learn", but not "Installs".  Do I need to do something to make it appear?

Comment: Are you sure its the Hub you are looking at? If i open Unity, i also only see Projects and Learn. if i open the unity hub, i see installs aswell.

Comment: Ah. Ok. Maybe that's the problem. I'll go and see how to download the Hub. From the instructions, I thought it was a direct link - obviously not! Thanks!